# Change vertical characters to horizontal

Tags: text-editing, keyboard-macros

I have the following data and want to change from Code 1 to Code 2. Is there any useful method to do that?

Code 1

```
11130101
11130102
11130201
```

Code 2

```
11130101, 11130102, 11130201
```

Comment: I presume there are more than three entries (with three entries, the fastest way is to do it by hand). The easiest way is probably a keyboard macro: do `C-h i g (emacs)keyboard macros` for information. Defining one to do it once can then be used with a numeric prefix to do it as many times as you want. They are useful to know about.

Comment: What @NickD said (please consider posting that as an answer).

Comment: Not directly answer but try to learn `el-macro` and how to save those macros which you do this will help and solve many of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace a newline with a comma and a space. You can use `query-replace` for that if you know how to type a newline character: `C-q C-j`. So all together, you can mark the region where you want to make the change and then type `M-% C-q C-j RET , SPC RET !`.